# Apache htaccess redirect directory and some contents

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently trying to get Apache to redirect any requests for a directory or it's contents to a single file.  The directory in question is `/press`.  This happens to contain multiple images that are being used by other pages on the site.  I want to redirect `/press` and `/press/*` to `/press-materials/` but allow any image requests (e.g. /press/logo.png) to be completed.  I've tried a few solutions and get one aspect of the redirect working but it doesn't meet the other criteria.

I'm a novice when it comes to Apache and REGEX (Something I knowingly need to work on) so this may be a simple fix.

Here is the htaccess call that redirects /press to /press-materials but /press/filename returns a 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^press/$ /press-materials/ [R,L]
```

After 6 hours that's as far as I've gotten.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to allow all requests to files which actually exist in `/press` (like `/press/logo.png`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^press/.* /press-materials/ [R,L]
```

This performs the rewrite only if no existing file in `/press` has been requested.

Another solution to allow only specific file types (e.g. only `*.jpg`, `*.png`, `*.gif`) and only if they are existing in the `/press` directory but not in a subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/press/[^\/]+\.(png|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^press/.* /press-materials/ [R,L]
```

More information about rewrite conditions can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: I played around with this and it originally didn't work.  I found that I had a directive pushing all requests to the index.php file with the L flag prior to these and it was breaking the /press/ statements.  I moved the index directive to the bottom and it's working now.  Appreciate the help.  I definitely need to get a good book on Apache. Haha